# Bot framework v4 authentication token cached

Tags: c#, authentication, botframework

I am using bot framework v4 authentication tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp .  I had setup an OAtuh connection using AAD app as per the instructions , while I am testing the authentication , I have few questions.

1)  Why does it still ask for Magic doe? Isn’t it taken care once you add Oauth connection setting in portal?
2)  Does it cache token anywhere? e.g. I am testing using below html file on my local machine. It works fine ->  gets access token on my credentials. But when I share the same file with my teammates, ideally it should ask them to login and use their credential to get new access token, but instead it does not ask for login and uses my access token.

My Code is identical to what is there in https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="webchat"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework- `enter code here`webchat/preview/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ secret: <my seceret>' })
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I host a qnabot on wordpress. Using PhP script to retrieve a token and store this token in a variable (in the Window object). Webchat can pick up the token (Html or React app).

This worked like a charm until I enabled Super Cache. Every user that started the chatbot on my website gets a new User id but the same conversation id and was able to join the conversation. I had to stop the chatbot (gdpr concerns). This behavior stopped as soon as I stopped caching on my website. Not a good solution (bad impact on website performance) but ok for now.